# Android Complete action using keeps showing after default has been selected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialog

I'm running into a weird issue in my app development.

At some point in my app, it would call an Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND) to launch Gmail,
and the "Complete action using..." dialog will appear.

Even though I check the default box at the bottom and select Gmail, the next time my app calls for
the Intent, the Complete action using dialog keeps appearing.

I can not get it to go away even though I already selected the default app to launch.

Any ideas why?

Example of the Intent

```
   private void do_gmail_failover() {   // If GMailSender fails, revert back to old method
   Intent   email_pic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);             // Commence choose photo action // Used to be ACTION_SEND       
            email_pic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, Recipients);     // Inserts Digital Signature address in recipient
            email_pic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, DIGIJOB);      // Inserts Track Number automatically in subject
            email_pic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriTarget);     // Attaches image to Gmail
            email_pic.setType("image/jpeg");                        // Converts image to jpeg   
   startActivityForResult(email_pic, RETURN_ACTIVITY);  
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);    

   LOGCAT.DEBUG("do_gmail_failover", "Inside do_gmail_failover function");
 }
```