# Android - 'Complete action using' keeps showing even after selecting 'Always'

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, intentfilter

I'm trying to use an intent to browse for images. I managed to get my code working but the only problem is that every time I choose the browse file button, the app always shows the pop up dialog 'Complete action using' even after Always is selected.

I still want the user to select from the available app installed and set it as default when 'always' is selected.

Do I need to programmatically save the user's choice? I have only tested this in Genymotion's emulator (Android's Studios emulator is very slow in my laptop) and my Lenovo S820 Android 4.4.2. Is it a specific bug in my phone or am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

I have searched everywhere and found this similar
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238315/android-complete-action-using-keeps-showing-after-default-has-been-selected), but it's also unanswered.

I am calling my intent like this:

```
public Intent browse(){
    Intent getterIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getterIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    getterIntent.setType("image/*");

    return getterIntent;
}
```